# Pipe a data frame to a function whose argument pipes a dot

Tags: r, lambda, dplyr, magrittr

How can one pipe a data frame to a function whose argument pipes a dot?

```
mpg %>% rbind(., . %>% rev())
```

> Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) :    attempt to replicate an
>   object of type 'closure'

Another example:

```
mpg %>%
  {
    . %>% arrange(manufacturer)
  }
```

> Functional sequence with the following components:
>
> 1. arrange(., manufacturer)
>
> Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.

Answer (score 20):

Wrap the dot to be piped in parentheses like `(.)`:

```
mpg %>% rbind(., (.) %>% rev())
```

Or, for lambda function:

```
mpg %>%
  {
    (.) %>% arrange(manufacturer)
  }
```