# Using rbind within a pipe

Tags: r

Is it possible to use `rbind` within a pipe so that I don't have to define and store a variable to use it?

```
library(tidyverse)

## works fine
df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Avg.Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup

df %>% 
  rbind(df)

## anyway to make this work?
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Avg.Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  rbind(.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate @MichaelDewar's answer, note the following section of `` ?magrittr::`%>%` ``:

> ***Placing `lhs` elsewhere in `rhs` call***
>
> Often you will want `lhs` to the `rhs` call at another position than the first. For this purpose you can use the dot (`.`) as placeholder. For example, `y %>% f(x, .)` is equivalent to `f(x, y)` and `z %>% f(x, y, arg = .)` is equivalent to `f(x, y, arg = z)`.

My understanding is that when `.` appears as an argument in the right hand side call, the left hand side is *not* inserted in the first position. The call is evaluated "as is", with `.` evaluating to the left hand side. Hence:

```r
library("dplyr")
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)

x %>% rbind() # rbind(x)
##   a b
## 1 1 3
## 2 2 4

x %>% rbind(.) # same
##   a b
## 1 1 3
## 2 2 4

x %>% rbind(x) # rbind(x, x)
##   a b
## 1 1 3
## 2 2 4
## 3 1 3
## 4 2 4

x %>% rbind(x, .) # same
x %>% rbind(., x) # same
x %>% rbind(., .) # same
##   a b
## 1 1 3
## 2 2 4
## 3 1 3
## 4 2 4
```

You can devise clever tricks if you know the rules:

```r
x %>% rbind((.)) # rbind(x, (x))
##   a b
## 1 1 3
## 2 2 4
## 3 1 3
## 4 2 4
```

`(.)` isn't parsed like `.`, so the left hand *is* inserted in the first position of the right hand side call. Compare:

```r
as.list(quote(.))
## [[1]]
## .

as.list(quote((.)))
## [[1]]
## `(`
## 
## [[2]]
## .
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would want to `rbind` something with itself, but here you go:

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(Avg.Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    rbind(., .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example slightly more useful than binding a dataframe to itself. Suppose we want to add summary rows to a data frame. Taking `mtcars`, we may wish to summarise `mpg` by values of `cyl`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(c('mpg','cyl'))
```

```
                     mpg cyl
Mazda RX4           21.0   6
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6
Datsun 710          22.8   4
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8
Valiant             18.1   6

<...SNIP...>
```

One way to do this is as follows:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(c('mpg','cyl')) %>%
  {aggregate(list(mpg=.$mpg), 
             by=list(cyl=.$cyl), 
             FUN=mean)}
```

Now, an application of the OP's question would be how do we append these rows onto the dataframe using a pipe?

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757192), we can wrap this in a call to rbind as follows:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(c('mpg','cyl')) %>% 
  rbind(.,  (.) %>% 
              {aggregate(list(mpg=.$mpg), 
                         by=list(cyl=.$cyl), 
                         FUN=mean)})
```

giving us:

```
                        mpg cyl
Mazda RX4           21.00000   6
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.00000   6
Datsun 710          22.80000   4
Hornet 4 Drive      21.40000   6
Hornet Sportabout   18.70000   8
Valiant             18.10000   6
Duster 360          14.30000   8

<...SNIP...>

Maserati Bora       15.00000   8
Volvo 142E          21.40000   4
1                   26.66364   4
2                   19.74286   6
3                   15.10000   8
```

The last three rows being summarised `mpg` values for different values of `cyl`.